# Predix machine default Log file location change

Tags: linux, logging, filesystems, predix

I'm using using predix machines for reading the virtual ports usb in my IOT project. Actually there were huge amount of data writing to the log file and which result in my linux filesystem corruption and this also lead to behave the root filesystem in read-only mode.
So inorder to avoid this , I'm trying to isolate the predix machine working directory along with the log file location to an isolated environment.
I've partitioned my drive and mounted a separate part of hard disk for predix machine. Now while running the predix machine, the logs are writing to "/var/log/upstart"(this is default location), I need to change this to customize location in my partitioned drive.

Any help appreciated

Comment: what version of Predix Machine are you running?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the log location in the org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg file under configuration/machine folder.

Comment: I've checked the mentioned location , as I'm new to this can you specify which part I need to change.